# Could not find iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk

I am trying to get my iOS SDK location but could not find it.

I have tried this link

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

and

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

But my mac does not contain developer folder.

I have tried to unhide this folder like library folder

```
danehog-Mac-mini:~ danehog$ chflags nohidden Developer
chflags: Developer: No such file or directory
```

Than i tried this link,

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

and

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

But it also no  use bcoz my application folder is empty

Comment: i want to add its location in to Dreamweaver for phonegap development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont look it in user/application mine is also empty. Look it on the left side of screen under favorite here,[image]

And than follow this links

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

and

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

Remember, Xcode.app is the xcode app icon you have to do right click on it and than select `show package contant` than follow link give above

Answer (score 0):

Do this following :

1) Open the finder window.

2) Now hit **Cmd + Shft + G** keys or  Click on Go menu & then click on Go To Folder Option.

3) Now Enter following path in  Go window.

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

[image]

Browse for associative folders

if you are using lion osx iOS SDK 5.0 – UsersHomeFolder/Library Directory is by default hidden

Hope it helps